# Print current drupal menu level

Tags: 6, routes, navigation

Hitting my head against the wall here. I've volunteered to print a list of the current menu items (at the same level as the currently viewed menu)

```
print theme('links', $secondary_links, array('class' => 'links', 'id' => 'subnav'));
```

Does anyone know how I would print out a list of the menu items at the currently selected level rather than just the top level primary links?

**Update:** 
Also just prints the children of the primary link parent.

```
      print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links'))
```

Answer (score 0):

print theme("links", array('links'=>$secondary_links), array('class' => 'links', 'id' => 'subnav'));

Comment: No luck with this, using the secondary links variable sounds right but it prints the exact same as the other line i've added (see update)